# Creating a Previous Type

Tags: typescript

I've got a `Product` interface (with `name`, ...) and like to keep changes to these products with a `Change` interface. A `Change` is a `Product` *and* all properties of `Product` prefixed with the word `previous`.

Not that creating the type manually would be a big deal - but I feel like you can create a type for this. My current approach is something like:

```
type Previous<T> = T extends /* all properties of T prefixed with `previous` */
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create such type by using template literal types, as referred in the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

The Previous type definition could look like this:

```
type Previous<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `previous${Capitalize<string & Property>}`]: Type[Property]
};
```

Then you could simply use this type like so:

```
interface Product {
    name: string;
    price: number;
}

type PreviousProduct = Previous<Product>;
```

Please note that the key remapping via "as" operator is working in TS version 4.1 and onwards.

Comment: Shouldn't the value typing be just `Tye[Property]` (without the function type)? But otherwise a super solid answer :)